# Blocks not visible when I log out

Tags: blocks, theming

In `Administration -> Structure -> Blocks` I have defined `Search box region` with `search box block` and `Left sidebar region` with `navigation block`. These blocks are visible when I'm logged in but when I log out the blocks disappear?

Do you where is the fault?

I have an idea where could be the problem. There are two files with page template - `page.tpl.php` and `page--front.tpl.php`.

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to grant permission to search content. `Peoples > permission > Use search checkbox`

Comment: This made the `search box block` visible but `navigation block` is stil invisible.

Comment: Then there are probably no menu links in the navigation blocks visible for an anonymous user.